# Unable to mount my Windows partition drives in external Hard disk

Tags: 14.04, mount, external-hdd

I had an old laptop hard disk which was containing 5 drives created in Windows 7. When that laptop was got complaint I picked the hard disk and started using it as external hard disk. Now when I try to access the drives using Ubuntu, it shows the following error message for all the drives. What to do?[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the ntfs is broken. As it is Microsoft proprietary Linux can't repair it. Hook it up to a Windows computer and repair the filesystem.